# Run direct by eclipse work but upload war file in webapps , then start not working

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java based web project , which I directly run from eclipse , it is easily run , but when I upload by using war file in webapps , it's give 404 error and each and every link have the same error .

Comment: Any error in your server console log file.?In eclipse your classpath is managed by ide. Check for any error related to dependency.

Answer (score 0):

check the context path of you JavaEE container.

for example: in tomcat, the context path is the war file's name, you need to add context after the ip address:

```
http://ip:port/{contextpath}/{controller}
```